# Did the Buddha visit modern day Assam?

Tags: theravada, the-buddha, pali-canon, history

During his time, did the Buddha visit the northeast state of India known today as Assam? If so, did he give any discourses there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The furthest east that the Buddha traveled was to Kajaṅgalā (noted in [AN 10:28](https://suttacentral.net/pi/an10.28)). This area is known today as Kankjol, and is located near the border of India and Bangladesh. So there's no record of any visit to Northeast India, but anything is possible!